# TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable (Pytorch)

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I'm currently self studying and implementing PyTorch.
While doing transfer learning with this tutorial:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html

I encountered an error in this particular code block:

```
image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(main_dataset, x),
                                          transforms[x])
                 for x in ['Train','Test']}
```

The error code is as below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-c83fc3ba4a1c> in <module>()
      1 image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(main_dataset, x),
      2                                           transforms[x])
----> 3                 for x in ['Train','Test']}

<ipython-input-41-c83fc3ba4a1c> in <dictcomp>(.0)
      1 image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(main_dataset, x),
      2                                           transforms[x])
----> 3                 for x in ['Train','Test']}

TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable
```

Which I am certain I have not used any module wrongly or any typos in this particular code block.

While searching the error code, I did not find anything related to this as well.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: You need to write `data_transforms[x]` instead of `transforms[x]` where the error points to. As it stands, you are trying to index `torchvision.transforms` (which you imported as e.g. `from torchvision import transforms`), hence the error.

Comment: Ah, now i understand. It must have been the transform variable that I declared in the previous block that confuses the compiler. Thanks!

Comment: If you did declare a variable called `transforms`, please change it and restart the kernel as it will shadow `torchvision.transforms`.

Comment: Yes, I realized the silly mistake, I forget that the variable name confuses the compiler easily. Thanks for the enlightenment .

Comment: I have posted your answer as the solution and credited you, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Quoting @Mustafa Aydin

You need to write `data_transforms[x]` instead of `transforms[x]` where the error points to. As it stands, you are trying to index `torchvision.transforms` (which you imported as e.g. `from torchvision import transforms`), hence the error.

I declared a variable named transforms and it confuses the compiler as it clashes with `torchvision.transforms`.

Hence the issue presented here.